# why the child item moving incorrectly with other multiple items including the parent?

Tags: interface, development

Why is the child object moving differently, when moving multiple items?

[image]

[pls check my video to Understand the issue](https://www.canva.com/design/DAF7hKQYqsU/mX1msWLUBL7KGKBA6i82eA/edit?utm_content=DAF7hKQYqsU&utm_campaign=designshare&utm_medium=link2&utm_source=sharebutton)

Comment: Hello, make sure that your object doesn't have a constraint like for example a Child Of constraint, if it's not the case please share the file: https://blend-exchange.com/